# Styling of description lists on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design

According to [this answer on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135909/188293), the `<dl>` (description list) HTML tag can be used in posts on Stack Exchange sites.

When I tried to use it in a Stack Overflow post, the contents of the `<dl>`, `<dt>` and `<dd>` elements (which were visible in the markup of my post, as verified with the element inspector in my browser) were displayed as plain text with essentially no styling added.

Here's the exact quote from my post (here, as pre-formatted HTML code):

```
<dl><dt>Permitted content</dt><dd>Flow content, but with no footer or header descendants.</dd></dl>
```

It looks like this:

Permitted content

Flow content, but with no footer or header descendants.

I was hoping to display a description list in order to quote a piece of documentation in a readable manner.

How about providing some meaningful styling to these elements? Personally, I'd find them immensely useful when quoting off-site resources such as documentations or specifications. It would be a boon to be able to use them inside a quote.

Comment: I have found a similar [request on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22972/better-style-for-html-definition-list-dl-elements)....from 2009....still open...expect 6-8 years to get this implemented....

Comment: @rene we are near the 6 years window... don't you mean 6-8 decades?

Comment: 6-8 years from the latest duplicate. If new duplicate arrives... yes, you guessed it right.

Answer (score -1):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

As of November 2, 2022 it's working

Term 1

term 1 definition ...

Term 2

term 2 definition ...